# How do I programmatically export a single Data Driven Page to JPEG?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcmap, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am trying to write a python script to export a individual pages to a jpeg. I am getting the error "PageLayoutObject: Error in SetDataDrivenPageID". Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
import arcpy
import os.path
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

ref_num = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
ref_num_str = str(ref_num)
ref_num_int = int(ref_num)

jobs = r"\\MSUKSERVER\BusinessMan Docs\Jobs"
job_fol = os.path.join(jobs, ref_num_str)
output_jpeg = os.path.join(job_fol, ref_num_str + "_BMS_plan.jpg")

mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = ref_num_int
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, output_jpeg, "PAGE_LAYOUT", 4679, 3308, 400)
arcpy.AddMessage("exported " + ref_num_str + "_BMS_plan")
del mxd
```

Comment: ref_num = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) is a string. If you want int, you have to convert it with int().

Comment: @Tomek Thanks I have tried that and get 'PageLayoutObject: Error in SetDataDrivenPageID'

Comment: It might be a bit messy to have to add another variable in here, but consider creating `ref_num_int = int(ref_num)` and then `mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = ref_num_int`.

Comment: @Arabella thanks but tried that, see above comments.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back, had a string `num_string` of numbers separated by `;` stored as strings, and casting to `int` did not work. I had to eventually use `map(int, num_string.split(";"))` to get the numbers recognised as actual integers. Though since you only need the one value, it would be silly to put it in a list. It seems like something else is wrong.

Comment: What Data Type is input value? How is it called in Arc: text, double, long? If it is double then use int(float(ref_num)).

Comment: @Tomek I was using 'String' as the input parameter in arcgis but also tried amending my code as you suggested and using 'Double' with the same result :-(

Comment: What OS do you use? If Linux you may check: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/38245-Data-Driven-page-issues-with-ArcGIS-Engine-on-Linux. Did you try to set your: mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = 1? Did it work?

Comment: @Tomek I am using Windows. My page ID's start at 40000 and I have tried several different page numbers with the same results. I thought it might be something to do with choosing page layout but removing that hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Did you check what says mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount? May be  your int is just out of range?

Answer (score 1):

I can get a single page with this. You can work back your string names.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

input_number_as_string = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
if int(input_number_as_string) in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    ref_num = int(input_number_as_string)
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Number entered is out of range. Please contact GIS Dept.")

mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = ref_num
arcpy.AddMessage("reference number is set : " + str(ref_num))


try: 
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\BMS_Page" + str(pageNum) + ".jpg")
except: 
    arcpy.addMessage("Cannot print this page. EEEEEEK!")

del mxd
```